# Problem with listing

Tags: listings, scrreprt

I think it's because of the Copyright sign, but i can't find the solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                           
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listingsutf8} 

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{ 
   belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip, 
   breaklines=true, 
   frame=L, 
   xleftmargin=\parindent, 
   language=C++, 
   showstringspaces=false, 
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
   keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black}, 
   commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black}, 
   identifierstyle=\color{blue}, 
   stringstyle=\color{orange}, 
} 

\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{ 
   belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip, 
   frame=L, 
   xleftmargin=\parindent, 
   language=[x86masm]Assembler, 
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
   commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black}, 
} 

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc} 
\lstset{language=C++,texcl=true} 
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8x} 
\lstset{ 
   numbers=left, 
   stepnumber=1,     
   firstnumber=1, 
   numberfirstline=true 
} 

\begin{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={caption}, label={lst:ceb}] 
// 
//  text 
// 
//  Created by XX on YY 
//  Copyright © XX. All rights reserved. 
// 

#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>  
int main() 
{ 
    \\ some code 
    output.close(); 
    return 0; 
} 
\end{lstlisting} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\end{document}
```

After this I get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8x}
```

to

```
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8}
```